# Splashscreen in android not working

Tags: android

I am using the code for splash screen for the android app for which the code was posted on stack overflow. I am unable to get the output. Here is the code.

```
package com.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

        private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 3000;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    Splashscreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,
                            R.anim.splashfadeout);
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the splash.xml file ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</LinearLayout>
```

please tell me how to resolve it. I also have fadein and fadeout xml files for the splash screen image.

Comment: "public class SplashScreen extends Activity {" double is typo error ?

Answer (score 0):

`public class SplashScreen extends Activity {` twice  in your code ..

make it single.

```
package com.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

        private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 3000;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    Splashscreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,
                            R.anim.splashfadeout);
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey i checked it and got it.Thanks.

But after the image is displayed the application is getting stopped getting an error as the application splash (process.com.splash) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.

There is an intent which calls the MainActivity class:-

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    Splashscreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);


But not working.Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MainActivity is added to AndroidManifest.xml. Also posting the exception stack trace from logcat could help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are not having the 'MainActivity' class. Check if its the right name. And make sure its in the right package and added to the manifest.